# Field is null after contstructor - spring

Tags: spring-boot, service, autowired

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/users")
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        System.err.println(userService);
        this.userService = userService;
        System.err.println(this.userService);
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    private ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse<UserResp>> login(@RequestBody UserReq userReq) {
        System.err.println(userService);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.login(userReq));
    }
```

userService is null inside the method, but it is setting inside the constructor

Cannot invoke "mscore.service.UserService.login(mscore.model.req.UserReq)" because "this.userService" is null

Comment: Have you tried by removing the final and the constructor you defined and annotating the member with @Autowire? What results it yield's then?

Comment: I have to change access of login method from private to public